# Moving template to separate files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mustache

In a Rails app I consume data from an external service in json format.

Right now I do something like.

```
json-data = $get ....
template = "<div>..{{whatever}}..</div>"
$('#target').append Mustache.to_html(template, json-data)
```

And it works fine. However, more and more the app and the templates grow I wish to be able to store the template in separate files (also because I'm starting to have some duplications).
I have created the folder app/assets/templates and put there  myTemp.mustache template. But, now I don't know how to load it into my script.

Any suggestions?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the awesome gem http://github.com/railsware/smt_rails . It is very easy to use

Comment: Thanks.  I will definitly check the gem out.  Even if I'd prefer not to use gems ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is great cast from RyanB [Sharing Mustache Templates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates) and here is the sample code [episode-295](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-295/store-after) in case you don't have pro subscription. Also look in [this](https://github.com/josh/mustache-rails) gem.

Comment: I'm aware of the railscast however I'd prefer to load the template directly into my script instead into the view. This because I may have several templates for each page and they are not always rendered (according to user behavior).  Thanks anyway.